# How do I get two finger scrolling to work when the mouse is over a flash object?

Tags: mouse, flash

Two finger vertical and horizontal scrolling works fine except when the mouse moves over a flash object like a youtube video. It then stops working and nothing happens with two finger scrolling until I manually find a point on the screen that isn't the flash. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is that the scroll events are being captured by the Flash object, but are not being passed onto the parent window when the Flash application has no use for them.

I'm not sure whether the responsibility lies with Adobe or the individual authors of the Flash applications concerned, but alas, I don't think there is anything that Ubuntu can do to fix this.